# How to print date time in the format `Wed Aug 21 2019 8:13 PM`?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to print the time in the following format, do I go about printing the date and time in the format `Wed Aug 21 2019 8:13 PM?

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
08-21-2019 20:13
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
Wed Aug 21 2019 8:13 PM
```

Comment: `print(now.strftime("%A %b %d %Y %H:%M %p"))`? Go through [strftime behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and see what directives are there.

Comment: `man strftime` will have a complete list of format specifiers that you can use in the `strftime` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string that you pass to `strftime` specifies the resulting output format. You can find the full table of the various format specifiers here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

For the format you're requesting, `"%a %b %d %Y %I:%M %p"` is the closest that is possible, however note that this still zero-pads the hour, so you will get `08:13 PM` instead of `8:13 PM`.

Answer (score 1):

the code following would be work:

```
print now.strftime("%a %b %d %Y %l:%M %p")
```